# Problem in Comoressing Image using Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I was trying to compress an image using fourier transform method. The program is successfully running but the compressed image is showing blank(only black).

```
Clear["Global`*"];
(*Load image and scale down*)
img = Import["C:\\Users\\Sinchan Ghosh\\Pictures\\Quantum.jpg"];
scaledImg = ImageResize[img, Scaled[0.5]];

(*Convert to grayscale*)
gimg = ColorConvert[scaledImg, "Grayscale"];

(*Perform Fourier transform*)
ftImg = Fourier[ImageData[gimg]];

(*Calculate the magnitude spectrum*)
mag = Abs[ftImg];

(*Compute the logarithm of the magnitude spectrum*)
logMag = Log[1 + mag];

(*Set a threshold value for the logarithmic magnitude spectrum*)
threshold = 3.5;

(*Truncate all values in the logarithmic magnitude spectrum below the \
threshold value*)
newLogMag = Map[If[# < threshold*Max[logMag], 0, #] &, logMag, {2}];

(*Take the inverse Fourier transform of the truncated magnitude \
spectrum to obtain the compressed image*)
(*newImg=Image[Chop[InverseFourier[newLogMag]],"Real"];*)
newImg = Image[Chop[InverseFourier[newLogMag]], "Real"];
{img, newImg}
```

Comment: If it is  a good idea to truncate small amplitudes: see results. Then: the exp and the +1 map is missing. and finally, the image data have to be reversed top down, A better approach is to mask the center of the fourier array, where the high Fourier components are located. Leaving 1/10 at alll 4  margins in both directions works fine.